# Unpack list of dataframes to create multiple dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, list

We have a list of 2 dataframes & want to create separate dataframes. Currently using the following code to achieve that:

```
for i in range(len(listOfDf)):
    globals()[f"df_{i}"] = listOfDf[i]
```

However, I want to name the dataframes as "Events" & "Occurance" respectively. How can this be achieved ?

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Comment: `globals()` also smells like a thing to avoid here, you probably don't want to be using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ordinary list unpacking:

```
events, occurrences = listOfDf
```

There's nothing special about doing this with dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following code:

```
dataframes=["events", "occurrences" ]

# Unpack the list to create multiple dataframes
for i,j in zip(range(len(listOfDf)),dataframes):
    globals()[f"{j}"] = listOfDf[i]
    print("Columns of "+f"{j}"+" are :")
    print((globals()[f"{j}"]).columns)
```